# Should meta be used for hypothetical problems?

Tags: discussion, support, per-site-meta

A site that I'm active on sees a lot of meta posts for hypothetical problems. By hypothetical problems I mean that a problem hasn't actually occurred, but people want to find a solution to that problem before it occurs. For example, trying to decide if a class of questions should be off-topic despite no one ever having asked such a question in the history of the site.

Is this an appropriate use of meta?

Comment: If it is appropriate or not is up to that community. I'm pretty sure it is an effective way to waste time and effort.

Comment: Can you give some examples of such questions that you've seen? Is this a problem that we actually face?\

Answer (score -1):

If you read the guidance on the ask a question page on meta, you'll see that it contains some helpful guidance about this:

[image: A picture of the ask a question page on a meta site. The help texts, which is circled in this screenshot, reads "Provide details. Show examples. Whenever possible, link to the relevant questions, answers, users, or page on the site you're discussing."]

[Examples are important for a reason](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1571/8960). Examples lead to better decisions. When you try to solve hypothetical problems, there's a very good chance that you'll miss something because you didn't have a complete understanding of the factors going into the decision.

Avoid hypothetical questions, and wait until you have evidence/examples of a problem first. Then make an informed decision.

Comment: This is very ironic, given that you failed to provide examples in your question here.